# How do I calculate the maximum amount of current a battery can supply?

Tags: batteries, current, circuit-design, battery-operated, servo

I have a few of these rechargeable batteries: http://w3.cebeo.eu/pdf_nl/4045126.pdf

I'm wondering what the maximum current this can supply is as I'm looking to connect 4 of these to power 3 servos requiring 5-6.8V and 2A each: (https://v1.cecdn.yun300.cn/130001_2012105006/DS3225MG_datasheet.pdf)

Many thanks

Comment: They are rated at 2.5A for one hour. Using less then that you should have no problem. As for maximum you will need to contact the manufacturer or find a complete data sheet.

Comment: Well I think you can calculate the max from the impedance which is on the data sheet linked, I just don't know how to do it

Comment: the servos are irrelevant to the question `what the maximum current a battery can supply?`

Comment: In theory you can calculate the short-circuit current of a battery. It is just Voc / Rs where Voc is open circuit voltage and Rs is the effective series resistance of the cell. The short circuit current will not be useful for your purposes right now, though. You are better off looking at the graphs in the datasheet as mentioned in mooshoomat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the "high rate discharge" plot you can discharge these cells at 1, 2, or 3 C which corresponds to 2.5A, 5A, and 7.5A respectively. So, the answer to your question is up to 7.5A, although this may effect the lifetime of the battery.

However, there are some other points in your question that are worth discussing.

Due to internal resistance and other factors, the voltage of the cells will sag during operation. Looking at the plot, you can extrapolate that if you are drawing ~6A (which is equivalent to ~2.4 C), the cell voltage will quickly drop to ~1.1V. With 4 batteries in series, this will only give you 4.4V for your servos, which does not sound like enough. You likely need 5 batteries to achieve the correct operating voltage.

Furthermore, if you want to take better care of your batteries, you can consider adding another set of 5 batteries in parallel to reduce the current load on each individual cell. Having a second set of batteries in parallel will reduce the discharge rate to ~1.2 C, generating less loss due to internal resistance.